# PyQt Reizable and draggable rectangle selection

Tags: python, pyqt, resize, drag

Is there a simple way to modify the QRect in the re-implementation of the paintEvent() method in the class SelectImageTool to make it:

- draggable to select different part of the image
- resizable with the mouse

or I've to use different ways that use other classes or approaches?
I've search with Google and this site and I've found the class RubberBand but I should have to reimplemented the class so I prefer other methos (if they exists).

This is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
                            QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QScrollArea,
                            QPushButton
                            )
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QPainter, QPen
import cv2, sys


from PIL import Image


I_MAX_CROP_IMAGE_WIDTH = 500

class SelectImageTool(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, mStrImageName, mFlScaleFactor):
        super().__init__()
        self.aStrImageName=mStrImageName
        self.iPosX0 = 0
        self.iPosY0 = 0
        self.iPosX1 = 0
        self.iPosY1 = 0
        self.aFlScaleFactor=mFlScaleFactor
        self.blnMousePress = False
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.blnMousePress = True
        self.iPosX0 = event.x()
        self.iPosY0 = event.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.blnMousePress = False
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.blnMousePress:
            self.iPosX1 = event.x()
            self.iPosY1 = event.y()
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        rctCropArea =QRect(self.iPosX0, self.iPosY0, abs(self.iPosX1-self.iPosX0), abs(self.iPosY1-self.iPosY0))
        pntSelectionRectangle = QPainter(self)
        pntSelectionRectangle.setPen(QPen(Qt.red,4,Qt.DashLine))
        pntSelectionRectangle.drawRect(rctCropArea)
        

    def setSelectionEdge(self):
       
        iScalePosX0 = self.scaleCoordinates(self.iPosX0)
        iScalePosX1 = self.scaleCoordinates(self.iPosX1)
        iScalePosY0 = self.scaleCoordinates(self.iPosY0)
        iScalePosY1 = self.scaleCoordinates(self.iPosY1)
        
        iLeft = iScalePosX0
        iTop = iScalePosY0
        iWidth = abs(iScalePosX1-iScalePosX0)
        iHeight = abs(iScalePosY1-iScalePosY0)
        iRight = iLeft+iWidth
        iBottom = iTop+iHeight
        print (str(iLeft) + " " + str(iTop) + " "+  str(iRight) + " " +  str(iBottom))
        
        return iLeft, iTop, iRight, iBottom
        

    def scaleCoordinates(self,mIntCoordinate):
        
        return round(self.aFlScaleFactor*mIntCoordinate)
                
    
        
    def cropImageSelection(self):
        
        iLeft, iTop, iRight, iBottom = self.setSelectionEdge()
        
        try:
            imgSourcePicture = Image.open(self.aStrImageName)

            tupSize = imgSourcePicture.size
            
            iLeft = self.checkCoordinateLimit(iLeft, 0)
            iTop = self.checkCoordinateLimit(iTop, 0)          
            iRight = self.checkCoordinateLimit(iRight, tupSize[0])
            iBottom = self.checkCoordinateLimit(iBottom, tupSize[1])
            
            imgCropped = imgSourcePicture.crop((iLeft, iTop, iRight, iBottom))
            
            imgCropped.save("cropped.jpg")

        except IOError:
            pass
        

    def checkCoordinateLimit(self,mIntCoord, mIntLimit):
        
        if mIntLimit==0:
            iCoord = mIntCoord if mIntCoord >=mIntLimit else mIntLimit
        else:
            iCoord = mIntCoord if mIntCoord <=mIntLimit else mIntLimit
    
        return iCoord


        
class ImageCropperBox(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(600, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Seleziona la parte dell\'immagine da salvare')
        
        strImgName = "1.jpg"
        imgSourceImage = cv2.imread(strImgName)
        pxmSourceImage, iWidth, iHeight = self.createPixMap(imgSourceImage)
        
        if iWidth>I_MAX_CROP_IMAGE_WIDTH:
            pxmSourceImage = pxmSourceImage.scaledToWidth(I_MAX_CROP_IMAGE_WIDTH)
            flScaleFactor = round(iWidth/I_MAX_CROP_IMAGE_WIDTH,2)
        else:
            flScaleFactor=1
        
        self.sitImageLabel = SelectImageTool(strImgName, flScaleFactor)
        self.sitImageLabel.setStyleSheet("background:navy")
        self.sitImageLabel.setFixedSize(pxmSourceImage.width(), pxmSourceImage.height())
        self.sitImageLabel.setPixmap(pxmSourceImage)
        self.sitImageLabel.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
        
        widImagePanel = QWidget()
        layvImagePanel = QVBoxLayout()
        saImagePanel = QScrollArea()
        
        widImgBox = QWidget()
        layvImgBox = QVBoxLayout()

        widButtonBox = QWidget()
        layhButtonBox = QHBoxLayout()
        
        widImgBox.setLayout(layvImgBox)
        
        widButtonBox.setLayout(layhButtonBox)
        
        butSave = QPushButton("Salva l'immagine")
        butDelete = QPushButton("Elimina l'immagine")
        
        butSave.clicked.connect(lambda state: self.saveImageSelection(self.sitImageLabel))
        
        layhButtonBox.addWidget(butSave)
        layhButtonBox.addWidget(butDelete)        
        
        widImagePanel.setLayout(layvImagePanel)
        saImagePanel.setWidget(widImagePanel)
        self.setScrollAreaProperties(saImagePanel)
        
        layvImagePanel.addWidget(widImgBox)
        layvImagePanel.addWidget(widButtonBox)

        layvImgBox.addWidget(self.sitImageLabel)
        self.setCentralWidget(saImagePanel)
        
        
    def setScrollAreaProperties(self, saImgBox):
        saImgBox.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        saImgBox.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        saImgBox.setWidgetResizable(True)
        
        
    def createPixMap(self, imgSourceImage):

        iHeight, iWidth, bytesPerComponent = imgSourceImage.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * iWidth
        cv2.cvtColor(imgSourceImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, imgSourceImage)
        QImg = QImage(imgSourceImage.data, iWidth, iHeight, bytesPerLine,QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pxmSourceImage = QPixmap.fromImage(QImg)
        
        return pxmSourceImage, iWidth,iHeight


    def saveImageSelection(self, msitImageLabel):
        msitImageLabel.cropImageSelection()
       
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    icbMain = ImageCropperBox()
    icbMain.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If by "is there a simple way" you mean "is there something that does that already with just a function for each of those things", then no. You have to properly implement the mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent, tracking the cursor position related to the current rectangle, and then decide on your own if that mouse movement would cause a drag or resize.

Comment: No, I mean: can I use the method I've already written (even if I've to modify them) or is it the wrong way and I've to use RubberBand  or other classes?

Comment: QRubberBand is a QWidget, which implies lots of things, but mostly: 1. it has to be created as a child of the widget (the QLabel, in this case); 2. it relies on QWidget functions (including visibility and event handling); 3. it's painted by Qt, so by default it uses the current style and option, meaning you have no direct control on its display, unless you subclass it and override its paint event. It's up to you to decide if it suits your needs or not, you can even create your own subclass of QWidget for that.

Comment: Besides that. 1. Please try to provide more *minimal* examples in your questions: at least half of your code is completely unrelated to the question; 2. You don't need cv to read images, and you can use [`QImage.rgbSwapped`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#rgbSwapped); 3. You can check `event.buttons()` in the mouseMoveEvent instead of using a variable; 4. QRect can be constructed with pairs of QPoint, so you can just store the `event.pos()` of mouse press/move events, and then paint `QRect(start, end)`; 5. You should not paint anything if the rect is null (start and end are the same);